# How to make a grid item inside a max-width container to span the full width?

Tags: css, css-grid

CSS grid is located on a page with a `max-width`:

[image]

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.first-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: tomato;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .max-width {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .first-grid-item {
    grid-column: 1 / 9;
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On smaller screens, the layout changes and the second grid item is placed below the first one:

[image]

Now, a new requirement comes in to add a full-width background color to the second item on the smaller screens so it looks like this:

[image]

How would you achieve this?

---

**Notes**:

- The grid can appear in the middle of a page somewhere, it's not necessarily the only element on the page. Example: [here](https://jsbin.com/duvorulopa/1/edit?html,css,output)
- Grid items can have variable height which isn't known in advance. Example: [here](https://jsbin.com/zomosomoro/1/edit?html,css,output)
- When the screen size is:

  - below 400px - the grid should occupy the full screen size.
  - between 400px and 575px (inclusive) - the grid should occupy exactly `400px` (which is the `max-width` on smaller screens).
  - at least 576px - the grid should occupy exactly `500px` (which is the `max-width` on larger screens).
- You are allowed to change the HTML if you think there is a more natural way to implement this. Just make sure that elements don't move from where they need to be.

Comment: Not enough information to decide which is the best approach, Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xgkfe8wv/) ? or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c0agbps4/)

Comment: @ZohirSalak Your solutions assume that grid is the only element on the screen, which is not necessarily the case. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Here's a hacky idea https://jsfiddle.net/fgtosjuz/

Comment: @ZohirSalak Somewhat hacky, I agree. It also has the unwanted horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On small screen you don't really need a grid.

Here is my try:

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.first-grid-item{
  max-width: 400px; /* Only restrict the first item */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.first-grid-item {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding:0 calc(50% - 200px); /* to have the content inside the 400px (remove this if not)*/
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .max-width {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* only here we need the grid */
  .grid {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }
  /**/
  .first-grid-item {
    grid-column: 1 / 9;
    margin:0; /* reset margin */
    max-width: 100%; /* reset max-width */
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding:0; /* reset padding */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it like below:

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.first-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / 9;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  grid-column: 9 / 13;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .max-width {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .grid {
    display: block;
  }
  .first-grid-item {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 0 calc(50% - 200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To have the different coloration, mutliple background can easily do it

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.first-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / 9;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  grid-column: 9 / 13;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(lightblue,lightblue) content-box,
    tomato;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .max-width {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .grid {
    display: block;
  }
  .first-grid-item {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    padding: 0 calc(50% - 200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this is using a `::before` and `::after` element on the `second-grid-item` and overflowing the `body`. You would need to essentially set `overflow:  hidden` on the body for this to work so it doesn't set horizontal scrolling:

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.first-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

.second-grid-item::before,
.second-grid-item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
  width: calc( 100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
  background: powderblue;
}

.second-grid-item::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -50%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .first-grid-item {
    grid-column: 1 / 9;
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
  }
  .second-grid-item::before,
  .second-grid-item::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam.
      Consequat luctus tempus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/qBOMopG

Answer (score 0):

Why not Simply move the width constraint to the grid ?

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}


/* Became .wrapper */


/* .max-width {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.first-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: tomato;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  /* Became .wrapper */
  /* .max-width {
    max-width: 500px;
  } */
  .first-grid-item {
    grid-column: 1 / 9;
  }
  .second-grid-item {
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
  }
}


/* New */

.grid {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, orange) 0 100% / 100% 50% no-repeat;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .grid {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.
</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="first-grid-item">First</div>
    <div class="second-grid-item">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
</p>
```